# skip lines while reading text files from ksh

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have a text file having some names line by line. 
I am reading this file through KornShell (ksh) and getting those names and performing some operations in loop.
I want to put some comment in the text file for readability (i.e., lines starting with # are comments an no need to read that).
So, what I want is to read the lines which are not starting with # symbol.

In ksh, I am reading like this:

```
while read base
do
---
---
done<file
```

I tried to use grep, but is is not working.
I want the correct syntax to achieve it in ksh.

Answer (score 1):

You can do for example this (read.sh):

```
#!/bin/ksh

while read line
do
    [[ $line = \#* ]] && continue

    echo $line
done < read.sh
```

Comment: what that part will do..? I want to perform operation on lines not starting eith # .. can u expalain a bit

Comment: continue is like continue in any other language - it will "skip to the end of the loop" and in effect read the next line. So at the place where I do echo $line you can perform your operations because at that point you know that $line doesn't start with #

Comment: The double brackets are just a test operator with pattern matching (it matches everything starting with hash, the hash has to be escaped because otherwise it would be interpreted as a comment in the script): http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/test.1.asp

Comment: Or equivalently `grep -v '^#' read.sh | while read line; do echo "$line"; done`

Answer (score 0):

How about this (edited to include full code snippet):

```
while read base
do
    # skip comments
    [ -z "`echo $base | grep '^#'`" ] || continue
    # handle remaining lines here
done<file
```

But the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20774827/1467943) contains a much more concise and `ksh`-ish solution.

Comment: where to include this condition . can u plz eloborate..?